# Vuejs three requests are sent to server instead of one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I’ve got one component (template) **table-news** which I use to display different data.
When I click on the button it pass button’s name to my component (button's name mean which data user want to see: news, e-mail or etc.), so I get needed data type to display
**So, problem is**: when I click on button I get 3 requests to my server. I think it's because **table-news** is rendered three times, but user see only one part. How can I fix it? Only use 3 different components (template)?

```
<el-tabs @tab-click="handleClick" active-name="first">
       <el-tab-pane label="firstTab" name="first">
         <table-news></table-news>
       </el-tab-pane>
       <el-tab-pane label="secondTab" name="second">
         <table-news></table-news>
       </el-tab-pane>
       <el-tab-pane label="thirdTab" name="third">
         <table-news></table-news>
       </el-tab-pane>
     </el-tabs>
   </el-tab-pane>


   methods: {
     handleClick(tab){
       this.$bus.$emit('setNewsType', tab.name)
     }
   }
```

In `table-news` something like this:

```
data(){
    return{
      newsType: 'first'
    },
    watch: {
      newsType: function(){
        this.fetch()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      fetch() {
        services.getSomeDataFromServer(this.newsType).then(data=>{})
      },
       setNewsType(type){
       this.newsType = type;
     },
    mounted() {
      this.$bus.$on('setNewsType', this.setNewsType)
      this.fetch();
    }
```

Comment: Use your browser's debugger to find out what's triggering the requests

Comment: Your `data()` appears to be missing an ending curly brace. Could this be related to your issue? If it's not a syntax issue, try changing the number of tab elements. Does the number of tabs consistently match the number of server requests regardless of quantity? That's an important consideration. Beyond that, we can only speculate because it's possible that you've omitted the most important code snippets.

Comment: @B.Fleming I know why this happend: becouse I used $bus on my element, so yes, it's correlated between number of  tabs and  server requests. When I clicked on one button emit happened to all three. Questions is how can I avoid this? Use three different components? Only one way?